# What can I do, applied for many internal jobs

Tags: interviewing, job-search

I have been at my company for going on 12 years, my total compensation is down 70%. My base has remained the same with almost no raises since I joined the company my, I was ok with this since my incentive side was growing. Since 2008 I am down 70%, but that is not my issue. I have been performing at a very high level and it is reflected in my reviews. My issue is that my area in the bank is moving into a BAU direction and typically within the firm you apply for other jobs. I have applied for maybe a 100 positions that I am more than qualified for. Almost everyone of the positions I have never received an interview but after a couple of weeks receive an email that while my background aligns to the position they decided to pursue other candidates. I have over 80 of these emails. I had three inquiries and each of they have wanted to reduce my pay and I cannot afford to take a salary hit. I'm afraid to go to HR, nothing is ever off the record at these large financial institutions, I know this because when I managed a large group they always would come to me when an employee contacted them and after they spoke with them. I also know of a standard practice at these large firms that they post the position they already have someone in for the position. My boss had told we needed to look for positions last year. Before he moved to a new position he looked at this and couldn't believe it. He reviewed the position I was applying and agreed they were in my sweet spot.he is about 10 years younger then me and wouldn't say anything else about it when I sent him all of the emails. At my age it is very difficult to go to a new firm. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried applying to other firms?

Comment: Please modify and provide more specifics of your industry, terminology utilized (BAU), country, etc...  This is for all work places and it's hard to tell from your description what environment/job you are actually doing and the goal besides "get another job"...

Comment: this post is rather hard to read (wall of text). Would you mind [edit]ing it into a better shape?

Answer (score 4):

Network, network, network. After working at a place for 12 years, you should have gotten to know and worked with lots of different people in lots of different departments. Seek them out, buy them coffees, hang with out them at lunch. Listen a lot and go easy on the talking. Learn about the challenges and opportunities in their world and look for potential matches or fits.

Once you find something interesting, try to go directly to the hiring manager. Ask for a quick and casual chat "exploring" the opportunity. Exploring is NOT applying. Exploring means you learning about the job and the manager learning about you. "Hi Mr. X, I heard a lot of good things about your project YYY and I heard you are looking for ZZZ. That's something that I'm personally interested in as well, would you have a few minutes to talk about this so I can learn more about this and can tell you a bit about me?".

Only if you both feel, that this may work out, apply formally. You can ask the potential hiring manager for guidance on how to best do this. They may have you talk to a few more people, they may run a full formal interview cycle. Be sure to agree to this or even offer it pro-actively.

Comment: Yes, 12 years you should have contacts all over the company.

Answer (score 1):

What you have been doing is not working. You need to change something. Here are some options:

- Have your resume and any other application materials reviewed by a friend or mentor to see if they can be improved.
- Apply for similar jobs in other firms.
- Train for other jobs.

Without much information about your location, job type etc. it is impossible to say which options are most likely to work. It is almost certain that you will not succeed by continuing to repeat what has not worked a hundred times.